# Telerik vs. Infragistics for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, telerik, infragistics

Yes, this is certainly a duplicate question, but I wanted to get some fresh takes.

My impression is that Telerik is a much more complete suite, but I'm really really turned off by the responsiveness of their controls. It just seems "clunky" in terms of responsiveness (I have a very fast computer and video card). Scrolling in a grid and transitions chunk, even in their latest demos where they claim to have good performance. I do like that their WPF suite matches their SL one in terms of API.

Infragistics has fewer controls and less theming possibilities, but their controls are very responsive. Scrolling in a grid is fluid, as are their combo menus and all the other controls.

I checked out ComponentOne and their controls seem analogous to Telerik's in terms of the points mentioned above but are a little less "pretty".

Any thoughts from other users of these suites? Basically, what I'm looking for is a suite that will be highly performant and responsive, relatively customizable from a theming standpoint, and have enough functionality to develop a LOB SL application without having to use multiple suites to satisfy the majority of common requirements.

Comment: In its current form the question is very subjective. If you state what you *actually* want to achieve then it might be possible to give you objective answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Telerik by far has the slowest (clunky) controls. We've downloaded datagrids from many of the control companies (Infragistics, ComponentOne, Telerik, etc) and found Telerik's to be the slowest as far as loading and refreshing hundreds of thousands to a million rows. I can't speak much for the rest of the controls tho. Testing speed and memory consumption, we found the C1Flexgrid was fastest, followed by Infragistics xamGrid, then Microsofts grid, C1Datagrid and last was Telerik's radGridView.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know it's not just in my head. Performance of loading rows aside, the "interactiveness" in general just "feels" slower/clunkier. I assumeing you're using C1?

Comment: I think you would be pleasantly surprised by some of the improvements that virtualization and container recycling have delivered to RadGridView.  We just shipped the Q2 2011 release and have demos featuring VirtualizedQueryableCollectionView that loads records on demand as well as a demo with 1 billion cells.

Comment: Then what about Xceed DataGrid for WPF?

Answer (score 8):

If you think about this, would you really ever want to load 100's of thousands to 1 million records in a grid or any control for that matter?  Well unless you're trying to come up with some marketing fodder?

I don't know of a monitor that could load that many at once to look at.  Even if it could, maybe I'm just slow but I can only process them a couple at a time.

What can an average user look at and process.  10 records, maybe 20.

I could see maybe wanting to load a 100 or so and not have to page to get new recors, but thousands or millions?  Personally I'm going to require filter capabilities and paging and if I have a developer trying to load 1 million records into a grid, we're going to have to have a sit down because the performance of a grid or any other control is not the issue.

Let's look at a multi billion $ company who has a site and it's sole purpose is to return data to a users.  I'm referring to Google.  Do a search and you get back around 10 records.  I just did a search and got 21,400,00 results.  If I don't find what I'm looking for in the first page or two (20 records), I know I didn't filter good enough.  I'm not not sifting through a million records.

So that puts your performance back to your logic of retrieving records and giving your users the correct ability to filter down the data they really need at the time.

How fast one grid shows 1.5 million records seems like  fodder for "bench racing" and who cares if it's sluggish scrolling because why pull back that many records to start with?

I apologize if I'm missing the point and you're just having fun with bench racing.  But I read you are talking about real world, LOB applications and if that's the case then we need to be realistic about the scenarios.

We use the Telerik grid and it performs just fine for real world LOB app.  Again though the users we write for can't look at or process 1.5 millions at once nor would they care too.

Also as you're finding out in this thread their support is second to none and I'll take that anyday from a any company we buy a these types of products from over whether they can load a million records in a grid or not.  Telerik, Infragistics or whoever.

For anybody serious about real world scenarios and trying to find a quality suite, the first thing to realize is who's on this thread trying to answer questions about their products.

Comment: I actually couldn't care less how the grid handles 1M rows. I care completely about how the grid handles 200 rows with 12 columns, scrolling up and down and left and right swiftly....and that's why I ask regarding the "responsiveness" not load capacity for these components.

Comment: I have delivered several 'real world' applications which needed to support ~200K rows in a Grid. Despite your opinion, this is often a genuine user requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at the following demo which binds 1.5 million rows to a grid with sorting and filtering enabled:
http://labs.infragistics.com/silverlight/lobsamples/2010.3/#/Samples/Grid/Performance/GridLargeResultSet

The "Virtual Collection" is another performance feature:
http://labs.infragistics.com/silverlight/lobsamples/2010.3/#/Samples/VirtualCollection/Scrolling/xamGridScrolling

Disclaimer: I am a Technical Evangelist with Infragistics

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to check the Performance section in our demos for more info about how the grid will perform with large data and/or real-time updates. Here are several examples:

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/Performance

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/UIVirtualization

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/RealTimeUpdate

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#DataVirtualization/FirstLook

Comment: I have and indeed your UI controls are far more clunky/chunky that Infragistics. I do like the range of functionality in your control suite...but a LOB app needs to be quick and responsive to clicks and drags.

Comment: The binding itself isn't the concern...but if you have a large grid (without deferred scrolling) and scroll up and down a lot at once or left and right (especially), the UI "chunks" or the scrollbar doesn't keep up with the mouse movement. Combo boxes with a large number of items also "chunk" while scrolling.

Comment: We've changed our templates loading logic and with our upcoming service pack the grid vertical scrolling performance will be much faster. We are about also to introduce our new horizontal virtualization with our upcoming Q1 2011 Beta (middle of February). Can you provide more info about the combo? Can you verify if the combo virtualization is enabled?

Comment: As Vlad stated the new controls are extremely fast and robust. I'd recommend downloading the latest and greatest and giving it a shot again.